# Django REST Framework - Serializer fails with querydict data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wanted to have a serializer which would read as an object of fields on a related models, but save as a pk value to the related object. Something like a nested model with `depth=1`, but with more flexibility on the nested model. Essentialy I wanted the following query structure

GET child/{id}

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "child",
    "parent": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "parent"
    }
}
```

POST child/{id}

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "child",
    "parent": 1
}
```

So I wrote the following serializers:

```
# models.py
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)

# serializers.py
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Write as pk, read as object"""
    class Meta:
        model = models.Parent
        fields = ('id', 'name')

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return self.Meta.model.objects.get(pk=data)


class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = ParentSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Child
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent')
```

This almost works as expected, but the child serializer doesn't work when passed a querydict. To illustrate the problem:

```
# This works great! everything as expected
parent = Parent.objects.create(name='parent')
data = {'name': 'child', 'parent': parent.pk}
serializer = ChildSerializer(None, data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
serializer.save()

# This borks
data = QueryDict('name={0}&parent={1}'.format('child', parent.pk))
serializer = ChildSerializer(None, data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
serializer.save()

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'
```

As a workaround I've forced `ChildSerializer` to convert QueryDicts to normal dictionaries, but I'd still like to know why the above fails and if there is a better option for this kind of API structure.